# How to delete security.config.cch?

Tags: windows-7, windows, .net-framework, ms-security-essentials

I have this file in my profile on a windows7. It seems some type of a security policy config of a dotnet process. I want to make a copy from that and then delete it.

But I can't do anything with him, even with local administrator privilege.

Unlocker can't find a process locking him. And, of course, I can't do anything with that, it seems totally unreachable.

What is that? Should I sign this file for deleting on the next boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to search for the handle "security.config.cch".

Maybe Intel Rapid Storage Client (if it's installed) is holding that file open in the default users profile preventing deletion.

When you find the right handle close it with Process Explorer.

Comment: It worked! As a big surprise, unlocker didn't found this handle, but ProcessExplorer did. I killed the processes and now all right! Thanks!